# Ruby on Rails: Update boolean record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, boolean

if my database is set to as false, whats the best practice in updating boolean value in database?

I can do it on console:

```
>> u = User.find_by_id(1)
```

What do I do next?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to toggle the boolean:

```
u.toggle!(:<attribute>)  # Toggles the boolean and saves without validations
u.toggle(:<attribute>)   # Toggles the boolean and does not save
```

If you want to set the boolean:

```
u.<attribute> = [true|false]
```

If you want to update the boolean immediately:

```
u.update_column(:<attribute>, [true|false])  # Doesn't update timestamps or call callbacks
u.update_attribute(:<attribute>, [true|false])  # Updates timestamps and triggers any callbacks
```

Comment: this usage gives an error, you should use u.toggle!(<attribute>)

Comment: Thanks, @Serhan. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
>> u.boolean_property = false
>> u.save
```

where `boolean_property` is the name of the property that you want to set to false.

That is the simplest way (just setting it directly), and there are other ways, depending on your needs:
http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/

Comment: im actually trying this in heroku, i'm in `heroku run console` and its saying undefined method 'boolean_property. Also, I'm trying to update it to `true`